# Netspeed not displaying in 19.04

Tags: networking

It seems to have vanished after I upgraded to Ubuntu 19.04. Please help.

Thanks and Regards, S.

Comment: Are you using the "netspeed" gnome extension?    Can you execute `ls -al ~/.local/share/gnome-shell/extensions` and [edit] your question to include the output of that command?

Comment: status please...

Answer (score 0):

Two issues...

Firefox 66.0.3 has a bug whereas it disabled all extensions (Saturday at midnight, I believe...). This was fixed with Firefox 66.0.4. So do your `Software Updates`.

Netspeed has a problem with 19.04 anyway, but there's a fix for that [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/104/netspeed/). You might check out `Vitals` [here](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/1460/vitals/). It can display various netspeeds (and other things) in the top panel.